# Regex words list to array for a JSON in Atom

Tags: json, regex, atom-editor

I want to achieve this using the **Atom search/replace tool** (with Regex on), otherwise it's not funny ;)

**INPUT**:

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "name": "Random data",
      "words": "super, long, list, of, elements, who, never, ever, end, I, mean, at, some, point, yes, but, not, now"
    },
    {
      "name": "Random data",
      "words": "another, super, long, list, of, elements, who, never, ever, end, I, mean, at, some, point, yes, but, not, now"
    },
  ]
}
```

**OUTPUT expected** :

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "name": "Random data",
      "words": ["super", "long", "list", "of", "elements", "who", "never", "ever", "end", "I", "mean", "at", "some", "point", "yes", "but", "not", "now"]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Right now I have this SEARCH regex *(but I don't know how to include the repeat in ATOM)*:

```
"words": "(.*),.*"
```

And the REPLACE:

```
"words": ["$1"]
```

Comment: easy with jq tool

Answer (score 0):

Search for `", "` and replace with `"\", \""`. Would not require regex I recon or would be fine with that too.

Comment: The issue is that I have other keys under `"words"` which can contain commas as well. I've shorten my input example to make it more clear. So what I wanted is to apply your regex but precisely in the "words" context.
But I will code a small script instead. I just wanted to know if it was possible directly from one Regex from Atom search/replace

Comment: My other option is to simply select a "words" line, then `CTRL+d ` to select them all, check the search/replace into selection and then apply your regex here. Should work too.